# Port number is not valid while connecting to sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

When connecting to SQL Server, it shows the port number is not valid.
I set up TCP/IP,it still shows Port number is not correct while connecting to sql server:

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you do a netstat on your PC to check if the port is open?

Answer (score 1):

If I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx correctly, it says the URL should be 
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433 or else jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\friend

Assuming the instance Friend is on port 1433.